# Rolling Rank of a Column in Pandas with min_periods

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I want to calculate rolling rank with window=10 and a min_periods=3.

Base Code:

```
df['RHigh'] = df.High.rolling(window=10).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).rank(ascending=False).values[-1])
```

This is working fine. But if I am adding a min_periods=3

Revised Code:

```
df['RHigh'] = df.High.rolling(window=10, min_periods=3).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).rank(ascending=False).values[-1])
```

Its giving me the same output of base code only.

Anything I am missing..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be different, see below:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'High': np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)})

df['RHigh_base'] = df.High.rolling(window=10).apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(x).rank(ascending=False).values[-1])

df['RHigh_min_periods'] = df.High.rolling(window=10, min_periods=3).apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(x).rank(ascending=False).values[-1])

df.head()
```

Output:

```
       High  RHigh_base  RHigh_min_periods
0  0.374540         NaN                NaN
1  0.950714         NaN                NaN
2  0.731994         NaN                2.0
3  0.598658         NaN                3.0
4  0.156019         NaN                5.0
```